# Crystal Reports: show only one row of joined table

Tags: crystal-reports

Have a join to a 'command' table which I would only like to return the latest result from. The query is something like this:

```
select * from TABLEA 
where CONDITION1 = '01'
AND CONDITION2 = '02'
order by DATE desc
```

when i change it to

```
select top 1 * from TABLEA 
where CONDITION1 = '01'
AND CONDITION2 = '02'
order by DATE desc
```

it works correctly if there's >1 record in the table

if there's only 1 record it doesn't display a result

Using Crystal Reports 2013. Any ideas or work arounds would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Fix for this was to create an intermediate table which use the max() function to find the id of the top row. then using that ID i could get the rest of the information